# Change UILabel text from appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, appdelegate

I have a UIViewcontroller let's say "DialerViewController" which has a UILabel 
@IBOutlet weak var statusText: UILabel!
,
 which has a default value of "pending", how can I change the value of statusText using an app delegate, let's assume the app delegate downloads a text from the server and needs to update the statusText after completion.

I am new to swift development, what is the best way to go around this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you download text from the server in Appdelegate?

Comment: Is the `DialerViewController` the only view controller in your app? If not... please provide some more info about your view controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `DialerViewController` is the only view controller in your app you can address it like this...

```
(window?.rootViewController as? DialerViewController)?.statusText?.text = "YOURTEXT"
```

Another option would be to make the `DialerViewController` instance observe some specific notification and post this notification in the app delegate when the text was downloaded from the server.

```
// create an extension for your own notification
extension Notification.Name {
    static let textWasDownloadedNotification = Notification.Name("textWasDownloadedNotification")
}

class DialerViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // make your dialer view controller listen to your new notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateLabel), name: .textWasDownloadedNotification, object: nil)
    }

    // function that gets called when a notification is received
    @objc func updateLabel(_ notification: Notification) {
        // get the new text from the notification's `userInfo` dictionary
        let text = notification.userInfo?["text"] as? String
        // update the label
        statusText.text = text
    }

}

// somewhere in your app delegate...

// prepare the `userInfo` dictionary with the information that is needed
let userInfo = ["text": "This is the new text."]
// post the notification
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .textWasDownloadedNotification,
                                    object: nil,
                                    userInfo: userInfo)
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter.

Comment: The biggest issue with this answer is that the App Delegate is the last place any of this should be done. The App Delegate absolutely should not be directly updating a view controller's label. If anything, the App Delegate should pass new data to the view controller and the view controller should update its own label with the data. But even that isn't very good because the App Delegate shouldn't be responsible for loading data.

Comment: @rmaddy Those are definitely arguments to be discussed and worth mentioning. Nevertheless the question was "how can I change the value of statusText using an app delegate" and these are some of the possibilities. So your comment should either be an answer or a comment to the question imho.

Comment: the idea to use the Notification center is really awesome and seems better, thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that because AppDelegate methods are called at specifics state of your application and the one that could be good is this one :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

But when it's called, your viewController isn't yet loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Loading from network it’s not AppDelegate responsibility, add new network service class and inject it to the view controller. Just get knowledges about layers architecture, solid. It’s very powerful for new devs, good luck.